# How to pass dynamic separator in key XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

How to pass dynamic separator in , here i passed '|' as static , when i declare variable in xsl and used this place it gives error.

```
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="'|'"/>
<xsl:key name="key-before" match="result" use="substring-before(Store, $separator)"/>
```

---

input  XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<results>
    <result>
        <Store>0180|1</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0180|2</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0181</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0183</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>abc</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>def</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0181|2</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0180|3</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
        <Store>0181|1</Store>
    </result>


</results>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param  name="key-direction" select="'p'"/>
<xsl:param  name="separator" select="results/sep"/>
<xsl:variable name="demo" select="substring-before(Store,$separator)"/>
<xsl:key name="group-before" match="/results/result" use="substring-before(Store,$demo)" />
<xsl:key name="group-after" match="/results/result" use="substring-before(Store,$demo)" />

<xsl:template match="/results">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$key-direction='p'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="result[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-before', substring-before(Store,$separator))[1])]"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="result[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-after', substring-before(Store,$separator))[1])]"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="result">

    <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$key-direction='p'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('group-before', substring-before(Store,$separator))">
                          <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="contains(Store,'|')">
                                <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(Store,$separator)"/>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            </td>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                           <td><xsl:value-of select="Store"/></td>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:for-each>

          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('group-after', substring-after(Store,$separator))">
                  <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="contains(Store,'|')">
                        <td>
                         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Store,$separator)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
                         <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Store"/></td>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
           </xsl:for-each>

          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<results>
 <result>
     <Store>0180|1</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
     <Store>0180|2</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
     <Store>0181</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
     <Store>0183</Store>
    </result>
 <result>
     <Store>abc</Store>
    </result>
 <result>
     <Store>def</Store>
    </result>
 <result>
     <Store>0181|2</Store>
    </result>
 <result>
     <Store>0180|3</Store>
    </result>
    <result>
     <Store>0181|1</Store>
    </result>
    
</results>

Comment: Is XSLT-2.0 an option? From where are you getting value for the variable `demo`? Won't that be null always?

Comment: I have use XSLT  1.0 and write now  use static value  in future  read from input xml.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is not possible (in XSLT 1.0). Neither the `match` nor the `use` attribute of `xsl:key` can contain a reference to a variable.